# How to run a code(crawl with BeautifulSoup) for a long time(months)?

Tags: python-3.x

So I want to scrape some petitions' data in Korea which is public.
I tried to scrape them every hour for about 3 months.

I used BeautifulSoup to fetch datas, and run it in Spyder with 3.6 version of Python.

The problem is, it keeps being frozen in every several days. When I searched about it, the reason seems to be a RAM since it keeps accumulating usage of RAM space.

So I'm now about to make a walk-around. And I hope you guys can give me nice advice to run the code for about several months since I'm quite rookie in programming.

This is what I am about to do:

1. Make Crawling.py code and convert it into Crawling.exe with Pyinstaller

- Crawling.py will collect petition data every 1 hour like 1:00, 2:00, 3:00 etc.
- Also it will make a txt file with timestamp in it(YYYY/MM/DD HH:MM) every 20/40 minutes like 1:20, 2:20, 3:20 etc.

2. Make Checking.py code and convert it into Checking.exe with Pyinstaller

- Checking.py will check the timestamp txt every 5 minutes after the timestamp should made. So it will check the timestamp 1:25, 1:45, 2:25, 2:45 etc.
- But if the timestamp is not revised comparing with the former time, the code must be frozen. So it will terminate former Crawling.py and re-run Craling.py again and it will give me some message that it just re-run it.
- If it is re-run, I will reboot my laptop so that it can refresh it's RAM.

The problem is, I'm not sure that if there is a possibility that Checking.exe would be frozen before than Craling.exe...

I want to get nice series data every hour for several months or maybe years.
Any great ideas about running it for a long time? Hope you guys can enlighten me as always.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: If it's accumulating memory to the point it crashes, maybe free up some memory instead of this rather roundabout approach/hack. Can you provide a [mcve] and explain the desired result? If it's accumulating data it's scraping in memory, maybe write it to file or a database as you work. Thanks.

Comment: @ggorlen Hello ggorlen. Thank you for taking your time on here. I'm actually working on a new code so it will take a while for me to edit with the minimal reproducible example. I will try to save the fetched data as txt, and clear variables which were used so that  it won't be accumulate any more memory.
But I'm still worrying if it will prevent the code from freezing tho. I have no idea what would make long-running-code freeze. I'll inform you whenever I will edit the question. sorry for that.